# Is handling the `Imbalance` type mandatory after withdraw or deposit?

Tags: rust, substrate

When using any of the functions which mint/burn the base currency (e.g. `Currency::withdraw()`), you're given an `Imbalance` return value. Does Substrate expect me to do something with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get back an `Imbalance` whenever you perform some ["one-sided operation" within the Balances module](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/2048) (`deposit`, `slash`, `withdraw`, etc...).

The both `PositiveImbalance` and `NegativeImbalance` implement the [`Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) trait, which defines a destructor function that gets called when a variable goes out of scope.

In the case of an `Imbalance`, the `drop` function simply updates the total issuance of the balances module to ensure that the sum of all current account balances is equal to the total issuance.

So by default, **no, you do not need to do anything with the imbalance returned to you.** You can just place the result of a "one-sided operation" into an unused variable like so:

```rust
let _ = <balances::Module<T> as Currency<_>>::withdraw(...)?;
```

However, if you want to, you are also given a set of tools to manage imbalances returned to you:

```rust
impl<T: Trait<I>, I: Instance> Imbalance<T::Balance> for NegativeImbalance<T, I> {
    type Opposite = PositiveImbalance<T, I>;

    fn zero() -> Self {...}

    fn drop_zero(self) -> result::Result<(), Self> {...}

    fn split(self, amount: T::Balance) -> (Self, Self) {...}

    fn merge(mut self, other: Self) -> Self {...}

    fn subsume(&mut self, other: Self) {...}

    fn offset(self, other: Self::Opposite) -> result::Result<Self, Self::Opposite> {...}

    fn peek(&self) -> T::Balance {...}
}
```